# how to view youtube clip without access to youtube.com?

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube, intranet

I'm trying to find a way to make my application to display my youtube videos from my own chanel to people that don't have access to youtube. 
Basically it is an intranet application. The users have restricted internet access.

please help me with some pointers.

Thanks.